# Mounting external HFS+ device with truecrypt - read only file-system

Tags: raspberry-pi, truecrypt

I´m trying to mount my external HFS+ HDDs on my raspberry pi with raspbian "wheezy". The disks are encrypted with truecrypt so I mount them with the command `truecrypt /dev/sda /media/usbdisk/disk1`.

But each time I try to write something to the disk, for example a new folder, it tells me 
`mkdir: cannot create directory 'newFolder': Read-only file system`.

I´ve tried to google that but could not find anything that solves the problem. 
I have already installed the packages `hfsplus`, `hfsutils` and `hfsprogs`.

Does anyone know what I have to do to write something to the disks?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just wanted to give the solution that helped me:
I had to disable the journaling on my disks. After disabling it the disks could be mounted without any errors.

Comment: How did you disable the journaling?